# How can I connect AWS EMR Notebooks to Oracle Database?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

In a CLI, I moved to hadoop directory(in EMR) and downloaded ojdbc.jar file. And I tried to connect Oracle DB using spark shell commands below:

```
pyspark \
--jars "/home/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar" \
--master yarn-client \
--num-executors 5 \
--driver-memory 14g \
--executor-memory 14g \

df = spark.read \
          .format("jdbc") \
          .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:USER/HOST@//IP:PORT/SERVICE") \
          .option("dbtable", "TABLE") \
          .option("user", "USER") \
          .option("password", "PASSWORD") \
          .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
          .load()
```

It is working but using a terminal is inconvenient for me. So I want to connect EMR Notebooks to Oracle DB and tried codes below:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

spark_conf = SparkConf().setAll([('spark.pyspark.python', 'python3'), 
                                 ('spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled', 'true'), 
                                 ('spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type', 'native'), 
                                 ('spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path', '/usr/bin/virtualenv'), 
                                 ('spark.driver.extraClassPath', '/home/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar')])\
                        .setAppName('SparkJob')
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=spark_conf)

df = sqlContext.read \
               .format("jdbc") \
               .options(url="jdbc:oracle:thin:USER/HOST@//IP:PORT/SERVICE", 
                        dbtable="TABLE", 
                        user="USER", 
                        password="PASSWORD", 
                        driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
               .load()
```

And got an error:

```
An error occurred while calling o97.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Is there any missing step, in order to connect to the Oracle DB from the EMR Jupyter Notebooks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this solution, First upload the jdbc driver to s3 bucket and copy the link, then you can specify the jars files in first cell(first to be executed). For example I did this for ms sql jdbc driver (you need oracle here).

```
%%configure -f
{
    "conf": {
        "spark.jars": "s3://jar-test/mssql-jdbc-8.4.0.jre8.jar"        
    }
}
```

Also, here is the snippet to read from jdbc.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession, Window, DataFrame,Row


spark_session = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("test") \
    .getOrCreate()     



spark_context = spark_session.sparkContext
sql_context = SQLContext(spark_context)

df = sql_context.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<public-dns>:<port>") \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .option("dbtable","<table-name>") \
    .option("user", "<username>") \
    .option("password", "<password>") \
    .load()
```

Comment: really great solution!

Answer (score 1):

You have kept the jar on master node. When you run from CLI you are on master node, your application master gets crated as `yarn-client` mode. So it will be in master node, and it can access the file in the master-node.

Now when you run via code by default EMR submit as `yarn-cluster` mode, and you can’t change that. This time application master created on one of the CORE node and on that CORE node the jar doesn't exists. So it can’t read the Class from the jar.

So what is solution:

1. Put the jdbc jar to each and every CORE node, as you never know in which CORE node the application master gets created.
   *Note: This is one the worst approach. Not recommended, as it will be hard to manage*
2. Put the jar into HDFS and access it via `hdfs:///<location>/ojdbc6.jar`
3. Put the jar into S3 and access it via `s3://<bucket-name>/<location>/ojdbc6.jar`